# Angular2 Get TemplateRef from any HTML Element

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to dynamically load a component into an HTML Element that might be anywhere inside my `app` component.

I'm planning to use the `TemplateRef` as a parameter for `ViewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(templateRef)` to dynamically load my desired component.

So I.E. I'm hoping it can look something like this

```
var myViewRef = this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(
  getTemplateRefFromNode(document.querySelector('.anySelector'))
);
this.resolver.resolveComponent(myComponent)
  .then(factory => {
    var newComponent = myViewRef.createComponent(factory, 0, myViewRef.injector);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not how it works, not at all. You don't have `TemplateRef` associated with *any* DOM node. `TemplateRef` is a structure created by the `<template>` element and only `<template>` element.

It is hard to suggest alternative proposals since it is not clear to me what you mean exactly by "I need to dynamically load a component into an HTML Element that might be anywhere inside my app component."

Comment: 3rd party developers are developing plugins to be rendered on top of our website. I'm hoping to allow those developers to provide a css selector for a load location of their component. Can you think of a way to accomplish this? Would it work to render the component in a separate view and then move the node to the correct location?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to load a component into an arbitrary location inside the content of your component?

If so, somewhere in the content of your component put a `#loadLocation` attribute on an element, then this code in your component will insert your custom component into that element.

```
@ContentChild('loadLocation',{read: ViewContainerRef}) loadLocation: ViewContainerRef;

constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

ngAfterContentInit() {
  if (!this.loadLocation) {
    return;
  }
  let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolve(myComponent);
  let newComponent = this.loadLocation.createComponent(componentFactory);
}
```